# How implement import/export functionality in dictionary?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I want to implement dictionary, which should have import/export functionality.
Are there any standard format for keeping dictionary in the file, because I want that my program support some existing standard dictionary formats(if there are any).

Comment: The simplest (and most compatible) format is to write one word per line, followed by a newline.

Comment: [Adan Liss](http://stackoverflow.com/users/29157/adam-liss)But in that case search will take linear time.

Comment: Not if the list is alphabetized and your search algorithm is clever.